# mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql

For school I have to build and basic website using PHP and MySQL. The websites function is to allow a user to register and then sign in and out. To do this, since I have no prior knowledge of PHP I was trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.codingcage.com/2015/01/user-registration-and-login-script-using-php-mysql.html). I got sever space with godaddy and using MySQL I created the database called details_db. I created the files the tutorial told me and uploaded to the server. Now when I go onto the website I get these errors.

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/pendrive34/public_html/dbconnect.php on line 12
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/pendrive34/public_html/dbconnect.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/pendrive34/public_html/dbconnect.php on line 13
>   Connection failed : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

This is the code in the file deconnect.php

```
<?php

// this will avoid mysql_connect() deprecation error.
error_reporting( ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );
// but I strongly suggest you to use PDO or MySQLi.

define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('DBUSER', 'root');
define('DBPASS', '');
define('DBNAME', 'details_db');

$conn = mysql_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS);
$dbcon = mysql_select_db(DBNAME);

if ( !$conn ) {
    die("Connection failed : " . mysql_error());
}

if ( !$dbcon ) {
    die("Database Connection failed : " . mysql_error());
}
```

I've been trying to find the answer to the problem for a while but my limited knowledge is holding me back.

Comment: dont use `mysql_` its deprecated since php 5.5.0

Comment: Is it a local or remote mysql server?

Comment: @Blinkydamo It's a remote server.

Comment: Then you may not have the right to access the remote server using root, you would need to use a normal user account with password.  Usually root is restricted for security purposes.

Comment: If it is remote `localhost` is incorrect, that is trying to access your local system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write mysql root users password to

```
define('DBPASS', '');
```

this line like..

```
define('DBPASS', 'password_of_root_user');
```

If you are trying to connect a database on remote machine (like a shared hosting), you have to change DBHOST, DBUSER and DBPASS to values that given you by hosting company.

Comment: but `using password: NO`

Comment: yes, that means 'you are not sending password to database'

Comment: this worked I entered the password and changed the details for the hostname and username to the information i used when i created the database. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: so please accept is as answer @CraigHarkins :)

Answer (score 2):

you need to provide the password in `define('DBPASS', 'PASSWORD');`

if you are working on *local* machine the default password might be "**root**"

`define('DBPASS', 'root');`

Comment: How does this differ from the other answer?

Comment: It doesn't and also doesn't help, either of them.  Further investigation required before an answer can be supplied.

Comment: answer is regarding to provide the default password if not known, instead of  sending blank string.

Comment: Yes, the answer posted 5 minutes before this stated that. (Also default `root` user's password is blank, better to go with defaults then guessing.)